# Есть ли универсальный механизм сравнения объектов в Ruby?

Tags: сравнение, ruby, рефлексия

Здравствуйте. Я изучаю Ruby и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что в этом языке нет механизма сравнения двух объектов, по значению, а не по ссылке. Ну то есть в каждом новом классе нужно переопределять метод ==, чтобы получать корректный результат сравнения. Это очень неудобная практика, и меня интересует вопрос, есть ли в Ruby какой-то механизм сравнения объектов без переопределения метода == в каждом новом классе? Возможно есть какая-то библиотека основанная на рефлексии, где это все проверяется или любой более-менее удобный костыль?

Comment: Можете привести пример "некорректного" результата сравнения?

Comment: Вот и пример:

    class Person
      attr_accessor :name
      def initialize(name)
        @name = name
      end
    end

    first_john = Person.new 'John'
    second_john = Person.new 'John'

    puts first_john == second_john
    puts first_john.eql? second_john
    puts first_john.equal? second_john

По сути оба объекта равны, так как равны значения их полей, а у нас сравнение работает по ссылкам. Конечно можно в каждом новом классе переопределять метод ==, чтобы он давал сравнение всех полей объекта, но это куча лишнего кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, как это сделать: можно модулем, можно наследоваться от класса, где этот метод уже переопределен. Покажу последний вариант (удобно, если все ваши классы наследуются от `Object`-а).

```
class EqObject

  def variablesHash(obj)
    Hash[obj.instance_variables.map { |name| [name, obj.instance_variable_get(name)] } ]
  end

  def equalObject?(obj)
    variablesHash(self) == variablesHash(obj)
  end

  alias_method :==, :equalObject?

end

class Test < EqObject
  attr_accessor :a, :b
  def initialize(a,b)
    @a, @b = a, b
  end  
end

Test.new(1,2) == Test.new(1,2)
=> true

Test.new(1,2) == Test.new(2,1)
=> false
```

Вам просто надо будет добавить `< EqObject` к существующим классам:

```
class Person < EqObject
```

Вариант с модулем удобен тогда, когда ваши классы наследуются от различных классов.

Comment: Большое спасибо! По моему, вполне хороший костыль. Надеюсь, что все таки со временем в руби появится нативная поддержка такого сравнения.